# Lazify this flatMap on a list of iterators

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Given this function, which I can't modify:

```
def numbers(c: Char): Iterator[Int] = 
  if(Character.isDigit(c)) Iterator(Integer.parseInt(c.toString)) 
  else Iterator.empty
// numbers: (c: Char)Iterator[Int]
```

And this input data:

```
val data = List('a','b','c','1','d','&','*','x','9')
// data: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, 1, d, &, *, x, 9)
```

How can I make this function lazy, such that `data` is only processed to the first occurrence of a number character?

```
def firstNumber(data: List[Char]) :Int = data.flatMap(numbers).take(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
data.iterator.flatMap(numbers).take(1).toList
```

Don't use streams; you don't need the old data stored.  Don't use views; they aren't being carefully maintained and are overkill anyway.

If you want an `Int`, you need some default behavior.  Depending on what that is, you might choose

```
data.iterator.flatMap(numbers).take(1).headOption.getOrElse(0)
```

or something like

```
{
  val ns = data.iterator.flatMap(numbers)
  if (ns.hasNext) ns.next
  else throw new NoSuchElementException("Number missing")
}
```

Comment: This looks good, except I need to obtain an `Int`, not a `List[Int]`

Answer (score 2):

Just calling `.toStream` on your data should do it:

```
firstNumber(data.toStream)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use Scala's collection views:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html

Calling `.view` on a collection allows you to call functions like `map`, `flatMap` etc on the collection without generating intermediate results.

So in your case you could write:

```
data.view.flatMap(numbers).take(1).force
```

which would give a `List[Int]` with at most one element and only process `data` to the first number.

Answer (score -1):

you could use Streams:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

One way of stream creation:

```
1 #:: 2 #:: empty
```